# Convert multiple files using command line with Python

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to convert all SQB files into BAK files format in the same folder (called "Today").

I was able to come up with Python script to move necessary (same day's) SQB files from ("Test1" folder) into a separate folder ("Today" folder).

Now, I need to run a command line to go thru each SQB files and convert all to BAK file format.

There is a EXE file called "SQBConverter" that will be used, and the command line goes like this (for example, for an individual file):

```
SQBConverter "C:\Users\Justin Dolt\Today\LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_2021042603.SQB" 
"C:\Users\Justin Dolt\Today\test.bak" "PasswordHere"
```

Here is Python script I have so far.

```
import os
from os import path

import datetime
import glob
import shutil

# Today's date recognition and concat
today = datetime.date.today()
today = str(today)
nohyphen_today = today.replace('-','')
revised_today = "LOG_us_bcan_multi_replica_" + nohyphen_today 

src = "C:\\Users\\Justin Dolt\\Test1"
dst = "C:\\Users\\Justin Dolt\\Today" 

# Move SQB files from "Test1" folder to "Today" folder
src_files = os.listdir(src)
for file_name in src_files:
full_file_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, dst)

# Not sure from here
for f in glob.glob("*.sqb"):
        SQBConverter....?
```

[image]

What would be the code like from here (to go thru all SQB files in the same folder and convert all to BAK files)?

```
for f in glob.glob("*.sqb"):
        SQBConverter...?
```

Added image later:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is:

```
for f in glob.glob('*.sqb'):
    os.system( f'SQBConverter "{f}" "{dst}/test.bak" {password}' )
```

If you need more sophisticated control, you can use `subprocess.Popen`, but this may be enough to get you started.

**Update**

You should have been able to figure out how to vary the backup file name.  That's just string manipulation.

```
for f in glob.glob('*.sqb'):
    os.system( f'SQBConverter "{f}" "{dst}/{f[:-4]}.bak" {password}' )
```